# How To Free the Memory Used by com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.EngineOutputRecord

Tags: java, sockets, netty, ssl

I have a netty application supplys keep-alive socket connenction encrypted by TLS. When the count of socket connection increase to 100000 or more, the jvm memory used is over 2.5G.

According to the memory report of mat, most memory are used by EngineOutputRecord(as the pic).As I know, this is the information for the TLS handshake, and is unuseful after handshake. I want to clear the bytes, but cannot find any method, any suggestions here? 
[image: Mat Report]

My code:

My Pipeline:

```
 @Override
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();

    SSLEngine engine = SecurePushSslContextFactory.getServerContext()
            .createSSLEngine();
    engine.setUseClientMode(false);
    SslHandler sslHandler = new SslHandler(engine);

    pipeline.addLast("ssl", sslHandler);
    pipeline.addLast("framer", frame);
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", myDecoder);
    pipeline.addLast("handler", myHandler);

    return pipeline;
}
```

Start Netty:

```
    ChannelFactory channelFactory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1), // BOSS EXECUTOR
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool() // WORKER EXECUTOR
    );
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(channelFactory);
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new SecurePushServerPipelineFactory());
    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
```

Comment: Does invoking garbage collector manually help? System.gc();

Comment: It doesn't work.The report is just after full gc.

Comment: Could you send me the heap dump for closer investigation? Please post it to the Netty developers Google Group.

Comment: This is the url for the dump:https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxNiSIOY-VI-TnJHWFNIVG5FMGs.